# creating slide up menu like in iOS 7 Safari's share/bookmark menu

Tags: ios, ios7

I'd like to create very similar sliding up menu as share/bookmark/copy/paste menu in iOS7 Safari.

What is the best way of building it?
Is there any ready made template in XCode or do I have to follow the same principle as when building the slide left/right hamburger menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

example action:

```
-(IBAction)sendPost:(id)sender {
    NSArray *activityItems;


    activityItems = @[@"example share / copy text"]; //needs to be an array because you //could add pictures additionally


    UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];

    [self presentViewController:activityController
                       animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```